# Convert count to float in HQL

Tags: sql, casting, count, hql

I have a query where I use COUNT to calculate the amount of sales of a vendor. I need to have the average amount of sales from this vendor in a month. That's just COUNT divided by the number of days.
The problem is that COUNT returns an int and if I divide it by a greater number, it just returns zero.
So, I thought about using this:

```
CAST(COUNT(sales) as FLOAT)/X
```

where X is the number of days.
The problem is that I can't use CAST on a named query. Is there any other way of doing it, so I don't have to use the CAST?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using createSQLQuery() method, it would automatically convert result into a decimal number without any casting/conversion.

```
List l1 = ss.createSQLQuery("SELECT 1/100 FROM DUAL").list(); //0.0100
```

But if it is createQuery() method, you can convert it by casting to big_decimal

```
List l2 = ss.createQuery("SELECT cast(1/100 as big_decimal),yourMappedColumn FROM yourMappedTable").list(); //0.01
```